# How to add Zod validation for array elements in react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, zod

I am using Zod validation to verify whether the given value is email or not and also checking the minimum length. But I am facing an issue, once the field is empty and clicking on submit button shows the "required" error message but when I add values into the field the error message is still there. I don't know how to remove it.

```js
email: z.string({required_error: "email is required"})
        .email({ message: 'Must be a valid email'})
        .array().length(1, { message: 'Cannot be empty' })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const objScheme = z.object({
...
email: z.string().email()
...
})
```

This should be enough, as an email can't be valid if the field is completely empty.

Your `.array()` introduced an error in your code.